# How can I make this Apple Script shorter? (quitting multiple apps via tell)

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to edit a part of an Apple Script to quit various applications at once:

```
tell application "TweetDeck"
    quit
end tell
tell application "Google Chrome"
    quit
end tell
```

Over all there are seven entries just like above.

Is there any way to write this more compact?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a list of apps and a loop. Just add new apps to that first list and they'll be quit automatically.

```
set apps to {"Google Chrome", "Tweetbot", "ForkLift"}
repeat with thisApp in apps
    tell application thisApp to quit
end repeat
```

Comment: Yay, this is very much what I wanted to have!

Answer (score 5):

```
tell application "TweetDeck" to quit
tell application "Google Chrome" to quit
```

tell-end-tell blocks with only one command can be written in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot pass multiple applications to the 'tell application' call.

Rather, you could use a unix utility that can terminate multiple applications at once - killall.

You can invoke this utility from within an AppleScript:

`do shell script "killall firefox Mail"` - This would terminate FireFox and Mail

***'killall' is case sensitive***, so you must first determine the process names of the applications that you wish to kill.

- Launch the applications that you will want to be terminating with the script
- Use the following command (in a Terminal window) to find their full and correct names. (In this example, we are looking to find out **tweetdeck's** correct process name).

`ps x | grep -i tweetdeck | grep -v grep`

With TweetDeck running, this will give output similar to the following:

`59127   ??  S      0:01.23 /Applications/TweetDeck.app/Contents/MacOS/TweetDeck -psn_0_21423213`

The last part of the path is the process name as it should be passed to 'killall'. In this case TweetDeck (...Contents/MacOS/**TweetDeck**).

So, we go back to our AppleScript and add TweetDeck to the string of applications that we are terminating. In addition to my previous example, I'd do:

`do shell script "killall firefox Mail TweetDeck"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! I guess this trick could work just fine. Then I could also use a stronger command to make sure that applications are quit.

Comment: killall is such a command. So far in my testing it terminates and "takes no prisoners". You could also look into using kill -9 instead of killall.